# Avoid choosing previous dates before today, without including today from datapicker on JS and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I am intending to use a datapicker that does not allow the user to choose previous days before today, but I do want that today itself is available. I did this:

```
 <input
                        name = "availabilityFrom"
                        onChange = {(e) => handleDateIn (e.target.value, e.target.name)}
                        type = "date"
 />
```

I am working with React so this above is part of a component, that has a state. Then with the value taken, I stored it on a variable to use its valueOf (), and created today´s variable also. Please notice that ***this.state.filterBy.availabilityFrom*** holds the value of the target, the selected date on the datapicker.

```
let today = new Date().valueOf();
let availabilityFromToDate = new Date(this.state.filterBy.availabilityFrom.split("-").join(",")).valueOf();
```

Then I used a conditional statement to get the desired behavior of the alert:

```
 if (availabilityFromToDate <today && availabilityFromToDate)
        {
            sweetAlert ("Warning!",
            "The entry date must be after the current date";
            "warning");
}
```

It works well, I got so happy when it did. But if I choose today's date, I got the alert message anyway, even if I am not using <= for today.
Maybe I am not understanding the proper use of valueOf (). Been having nightmares about this, haha.

Thanks in advance!: D

Comment: What is `.split("-").join(",")` all about? The `Date` constructor does not take strings with commas in it...

Comment: Use e.target.valueAsNumber to get date in milliseconds instead of parsing it yourself.